# Update touchscreen config in Ubuntu 22 under Wayland

Tags: wayland, touchscreen, xinput

I've spent a considerable amount time attempting to invert my XY axis on a touchscreen monitor on Ubuntu 22.04 under Wayland to no avail. Adding configuration details in "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/" does not have any effect. Adding a config file in "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/" seems to be ignored. And updating the "xinput set-prop" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" does not seem to have any effect either. I understand the reason, but I attempted all of those options anyway. I also understand that I could switch to Xorg, but I don't want to do that in this case. Is there any way to update any config options for a touchscreen monitor under Wayland? For some reason, one monitor I have has a swapped XY axis and it's unusable without a corrected config.